# Is this sentence structure correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

*`Ein anderer Nutzen für man eine Fremdsprache zu lernen ist, damit man Geld sparen kann, weil man für seine Wohnung nicht bezahlen muss.`*

Is the first part correct?
Also, is there a substitute for 'man' as I have already used the word a few times in the sentence.

(context is that you save money as when you travel overseas you can stay with your friends instead of paying for accommodation)

Comment: You can have friends in other contries without speaking the language of the country (because they speak your language).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A substitue for "man" could be "dich" or "Sie" or "euch" etc., but I would just throw it away. "Man" is wrong here anyway, you cannot use it with prepositions. It may be only nominativ singular.

"Wohnung" is the place where you permanently live. It's never used for a temporary accomodation like a hotel, hostel or like that. A correct word might be "Hotel", "Zimmer" or simply "Übernachtung".

"Damit" is not correct too. It has a different meaning ("so that, in order that"). The sentence "*damit man Geld sparen kann*" would mean that you can only save money if you do something what was mentioned in other part. Example: *"Ich lerne Deutsch, damit ich Geld sparen kann"* - *"I learn German to save money"*.

All in all: *Ein anderer Nutzen eine Fremdsprache zu lernen ist, dass man Geld sparen kann, weil man für die Übernachtung (auf Reisen) nicht zahlen muss.*

Comment: "Ein anderer Nutzen eine Fremdsprache zu lernen ist" is this correct? I would say: "Ein anderer Nutzen von Fremdsprachenkenntnissen"

Comment: @Iris it (the 1st sentence) doesn't sound good to me too.

Comment: Then why do you propose it as answer?